# How can i add one more extra row in cart page summary section below of shipping

Tags: magento2, checkout

how to i make the tax amount was only show in cart page and checkout page
i wan to add custome row in that page and that also manage by admin like enable disable

[image]

add custome row with custome numeric value in magento2 cart page summary

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this blog if you want to add like this.

https://webkul.com/blog/display-custom-price-fee-checkout-cart-summary-total-magento2/

Comment: hello thank you for your response i need with that also manage by admin

Comment: means what you need to be managed by admin ?

Comment: that custom row

Comment: enable disable and also add some number and title  from admin so that display on that row

Comment: yes for that you can add system.xml file and you can change code..First apply above code and let me know ..I will guide you for managable from backend as well

Comment: okay than let me i do